# Facebook sdk. Publish on people wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I developed an application a while ago that published messages on people walls, but I remember I had problems with sdk upgrades that restricted publishing on wall features.

Now I'm developing a new application that's supposed to have a similar feature, but not sure if it's even possible (I'm guessing it's not though), so my questions are, with the latest Facebook sdk:

- *Is it possible to publish a message on 'someone's wall without him granting permission for it?*
- *If not, is it possible to publish a message on 'someone's wall if he authorizes my application to?*
- *Is it even possible to publish a message on my own wall using my user credentials?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Facebook has disabled posting to a friends wall completely using the SDK, whether you were granted permission or not. [See the February 6, 2013 Update](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes). You should use the JavaScript Feed dialog instead setting the `to` field of the user you want to message.
- No. As above.
- Yes, you need the `publish_actions` permission to do this using the SDK.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nirajshah, any chance you could add a link to the documentation that indicates this?

Comment: I'm guessing it'd be possible to mention a friend on a message published on my own wall, is that so?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You should use the `taggable_friends` API for this.